# Tailwindcss doesn't provide a proper styles file

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Im using tailwindcss for my project. I run `npm i tailwindcss -D` then i wrote followind code in my `style.css`:  `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;` and then run `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`. But in my `output.css` file i have only 400-500 lines of code. Meanwhile cdn file contains thousands of them. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that is due to the **latest version of the tailwind CSS V3**. The JIT is enabled by default and it will **only render the respective styles being used in the files mentioned in your config**.
That is perfectly an expected behavior, this can give you a good lead.
https://youtu.be/mSC6GwizOag

Also you are using the **--watch** flag that will do the same.

Kindly try **upgrading to the latest version of tailwindcss**.

Answer (score 1):

Due to Tailwind's just in time mode, only the necessary code is generated to keep your project as small as possible.

Is tailwind working correct?

Comment: Yes tailwind is working properly. That is the new version of the Tailwind Just in Time compiler